# net module "socket.remoteAddress" value is wrong

Tags: node.js, sockets

I create a TCP IVP4 socket server in Node.js using the 'net' module, and it works great for almost all of my clients, but one client has an IP similar to (I won't disclose the real one):
`180.190.154.97`

but when they connect to my socket server and I console.log(socket.remoteAddress), the value is this:
`180.190.193.2`

Why would this be happening?

```js
// Import dependencies
let net = require('net')

// Create socket server.
const SERVER = net.createServer(socketConnection)

function socketConnection(client) {
    console.log(client.remoteAddress)
}

// Server code snippet
let SERVER_LISTEN_ADDRESS = '0.0.0.0'

if (Game.local) {
    SERVER_LISTEN_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'
    Game.port = 42480
}

SERVER.listen(Game.port, SERVER_LISTEN_ADDRESS, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + Game.port)
    if (!Game.local)
        postServer()
    else
        console.log('Running server locally.')
})
```

Expected result is that it should print their IPV4 value from a site like:
https://whatismyipaddress.com/

But instead it says something completely different.

Comment: What is the actual result? Considerar that in some cases ip addres can be masked in local

Comment: @Thecave3 The result I get is this: `180.190.193.3` which is wrong after I confirmed it with them.

Comment: What do you mean for confirmed it with them?

Comment: @Thecave3 I asked them to tell me the result of https://whatismyipaddress.com/ under IPV4, and it's different by at least 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

The result shown by whatipmyaddress it is not always the public IP of the single host. It could be rather also the IP of the subnet or if there's a proxy the IP of the proxy server. The fact that the address differs by a few units suggests that those particular hosts are in a subnet where a NAT service is active, or protected by a proxy or where the router acts as a VPN to the outside, encapsulating and sending the message to the server. In this case probably the entire subnet is seen as a single host.

In case you're using Express, you may want to use [request-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip) package in order to retrieve the IP in a more robust way. Since it seems you're not using express you should implement something similar to the first example shown in the link. For your specific case according the code you give:

```
const requestIp = require('request-ip');

function socketConnection(client) {
    const clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp(client); 
    console.log(client);
}
```

Comment: Returns 'null' according to the docs. I should specify I am not using express or any web frameworks because this isn't a website. 

It's a server that a game client is connecting to. Very legacy and a lot of hacks have to be made to get things to work properly.

Comment: it returns `null` to every case or just to some of them? Or just in the previous faulty case?

Comment: Every case.

```js
function socketConnection(client) {
    return console.log(requestIp.getClientIp(client))
}
```
> null